# AsyncTask stops application

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using AsyncTask in my application, but when it starts, it's like that it never ends. When I'm debugging after `doInBackground` application freezes and stuck in `ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)`.

Here's the structure of my code

```
class FetchSymbolInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {

        private Exception exception = null;

        @Override
        protected Document doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            try 
            {
                Document doc = null;
                //doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();//application freezes even if I remove this line
                return doc;
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                this.exception = e;
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Document result) 
        {
            if(exception != null)
        {
            AlertDialog alertDialog;
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(null).create();//////////
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Could not fetch from internetd\nPlease check your inernet connection and symbol name.");
            alertDialog.show();
            return;
        }

        Elements valueElement = result.select("div#qwidget_lastsale");
        String valueString = valueElement.toString();
        //getting number from string
        }

        @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
          }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(Document result) {
            super.onCancelled(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
```

And I'm trying to execute it like this

```
String url = "url";  //writing an url
FetchSymbolInfo fetch = new FetchSymbolInfo();
fetch.execute(url);
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this your actual code, or just a skeleton? I don't see anything here that should cause it to hang. It just sends a `null` to `onPostExecute` and stops.

Comment: It's just a skeleton, but I'm trying my code with the same body of `doInBackground` function as written here and it freezes again

Comment: show the code for `@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Document result) 
        {
            if(exception != null)
            {
                //print error
            }
            //doing some stuff
        }`

Comment: I just edited my post. But problem is that it never reach to `onPostExecute`

Comment: @nabroyan Are you sure it doesn't just stop inside that method rather than not reaching? Add `Log.i("onPostExecute", "Started"); to the first line in that method and see if it's outputted in the Logcat

Comment: @Zackehh9lives I put a breakpoint on the first line of `onPostExcucute` method, and during debugging I never reached to that breakpoint

Comment: @nabroyan If it's running on a new thread, does a breakpoint still get caught by the debugger?

Comment: @Zackehh9lives you're right, as it was another thread breakpoint is not being caught by debugger (as Visual Studio does).

Comment: @nabroyan Then use `Log` as I first suggested, that should help you out. Also, `AlertDialog.Builder(context)` is what you need, with context being passed from the calling Activity.

Comment: @Zackehh9lives I've already tried that and it worked. Now I use `Log` and `context` instead of `null`. Thank you!!

Comment: @nabroyan So your question is answered? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create an `AlertDialog` by providing a `null` `Context`. What you need to do is pass a valid Context from the `Activity` calling the `AsyncTask` by passing the Context to the constructor of the task and then using that with the Dialog:

```
class FetchSymbolInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {

private Context parent;

// ...

public FetchSymbolInfo(Context c){
    parent = c;
}

// ...

if(exception != null){
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(parent).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Could not fetch from internetd\nPlease check your inernet connection and symbol name.");
    alertDialog.show();
    return;
}
```

**Addition:** Although not directly related to the question, I think it's important to mention here than if you set a breakpoint in a new thread as the OP did, you won't hit it - you're better off using `Log` to keep track of entering/exiting methods/code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that you should be getting a NPE in.

```
    Elements valueElement = result.select("div#qwidget_lastsale");
```

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean by saying NPE?

Comment: @nabroyan NullPointerException

Comment: @Zackehh9lives that's right I returned `null` and `exception` was `null` to and I tried to work with result. And if I an exception occurred`alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(null).create();` line caused NPE. So there was lot of `null` in this piece of code